# How to write to Global Address List as third application with Exchange Online?

Tags: exchangewebservices, gal

I am looking for a way to write to the Global Address List of an Exchange Online account. EWS only provides name resolution against GAL. Is there a way to access this list in write mode as a third application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think Powershell is the only option. [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997686(v=exchg.150).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa997686%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)